# Infinitude of primes via Fermat numbers query

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've just come across the proof of the infinitude of primes using the Fermat numbers. The proof makes use of the relationship $$F_{0}\cdot F_{1}\cdot F_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot F_{k-1} = F_{k} - 2.$$This is probably a dumb question, but are the Fermat numbers the only series of numbers that have that relationship?

Comment: This particular relationship, or the relationship that all elements of the sequence are coprime?

Comment: Doesn't the relationship as given imply that all the elements of the sequence are coprime?

Comment: It does if the first term is odd.

Comment: does the dot stand for multiplication?

Comment: Yes, the single dots between the terms stand for multiplication.

Comment: The given relationship doesn't hold for the Fermat numbers. $2\times 3 \neq 5 - 2$.

Comment: @orip - But 2 isn't a Fermat number ($F_{n} = 2^{2^{n}} + 1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be any integer, and set

$$x_k=x_0x_1\cdots x_{k-1} + 2.$$

Then you have a sequence that satisfies this! In fact, as is not too difficult to prove by induction, the values are

$$x_k=(x_0+1)^{2^{k-1}}+1$$

(where $k>0$ - at $k=0$ we have $x_0$ instead).

Comment: Actually when making this sequence different than the Fibonacci sequence it would have been enough to just tak $x_0=4$, and so finding $x_n$ explicitly isn't necessary. Neat either way though, +1.

Comment: So can the relationship $x_k=x_0x_1\cdots x_{k-1} + 2$ also be used to show the infinitude of primes? Surely, it can't as $x_k$ is not necessarily  odd.

Comment: If $x_0$ is odd, $x_0+1$ is even, so $x_k=(x_0+1)^{2^{k-1}}+1$ is odd. Because of that, $\gcd(x_k,x_i)=1$, so the sequence can be used to show the infinitude of primes.